# Yakuake Terminal doesnt open when ANY window is selected

Tags: yakuake

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and Yakuake. I changed the default OPEN shortcut to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, but it only opens if I minimize everything and I am on Desktop screen.

My Configs below:

[image]

[image]

If I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> while focusing on any window. The currently window loses focus but the terminal does not open.

Also. NO way to make Yakuake stick to the toolbar so I can <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to it?

Comment: Why the gnome-terminal tag?

Comment: Are you running Xorg or Wayland? Please add that information to your question. To just Alt+Tab into a terminal emulator, you just use a standard windowed terminal emulator and configure a shortcut key to bring it to the front if it is running already for having the "pop up" effect of a drop-down terminal.

Comment: I gave up and ended up using `Konsole` and/or `Tilix`.  very good ones